# Teamviewer stopped working after disconnecting physical monitor

Tags: manjaro, teamviewer

I can't connect via teamviewer on my remote linux machine when the monitor is disconnected.

Teamviewer makes the connection to the remote machine but I'm always landing on the display management interface of linux but it doesn't show me a way to enter user name and password.

I have described the whole issue/process along with the remote machine's hardware on the following [forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/creating-virtual-monitor-for-teamviewer/124069/6).

Comment: Found the cause of this on the teamviewer [website](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/4256-use-teamviewer-on-headless-systems), but I think there should be a workaround for this, no?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution to this on the archwiki webiste.

In my case I had to:

1. install `xf86-video-dummy` package
2. create the following configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-headless.conf` and paste the following content

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "dummy_monitor"
        HorizSync 28.0-80.0
        VertRefresh 48.0-75.0
        Modeline "1920x1080" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier "dummy_card"
        VideoRam 256000
        Driver "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "dummy_screen"
        Device "dummy_card"
        Monitor "dummy_monitor"
        SubSection "Display"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Now teamviewer works at if a physical monitor is connected to the video card. Only thing left is to fix the screen resolution which is a bit small for my taste.